# How to specify IPN Listener URL for PayPal MassPay Requests

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-soap

I'm using the PayPal Merchant-SDK to send MassPay items.  I need to listen for IPN messages returned from PayPal.

I've specified the URL in sdk_config.properties with: 
service.IPNEndpoint=" ... "

but the URL is not appearing in the requests that are generated.

I've also noticed that the MassPay schema doesn't have a notify-url element as seems to be the case for other payment types such as "DoExpressCheckoutPayment".

Does anyone know what I may be missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that you can set the IPN URL for MassPay would be to set it in your account.  You can't set it in the code.  It needs to be set in your PayPal account, under your profile.

Comment: My Profile & Settings > My Selling Tools > IPN